# dcpromo of a windows server 2008 in existing samba based AD resulting in infinite configuration

Tags: ubuntu, samba, windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory

We want to add a new DC using windows server 2008 in our AD that just have 2 zentyal 5 based DC to replace the second. DCPROMO is able to get all informations but when start to configure the DC , the configuration never ends.    From the zentyal domain controller I can only see an infinite:

```
 [2019/04/17 06:30:53.470533,  3] ../source4/rpc_server/dcerpc_server.c:1644(dcesrv_request)
  Warning: 2 extra bytes in incoming RPC request
[2019/04/17 06:30:53.471189,  2] ../source4/rpc_server/drsuapi/getncchanges.c:1526(getncchanges_collect_objects)
  ../source4/rpc_server/drsuapi/getncchanges.c:1526: getncchanges on CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it using filter (uSNChanged>=1)
[2019/04/17 06:30:54.031139,  2] ../source4/rpc_server/drsuapi/getncchanges.c:2784(dcesrv_drsuapi_DsGetNCChanges)
  DsGetNCChanges with uSNChanged >= 1 flags 0x90200070 on <GUID=c2f90cf6-01eb-45c5-b379-a2f97011ae4b>;CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it gave 637 objects (done 1637/1637) 38 links (done 38/38 (as S-1-5-21-3824729860-2459181076-3710323013-500))
[2019/04/17 06:30:54.062038,  3] ../source4/smbd/service_stream.c:66(stream_terminate_connection)
  Terminating connection - 'dcesrv: NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER'
[2019/04/17 06:30:54.062212,  3] ../source4/smbd/process_single.c:114(single_terminate)
  single_terminate: reason[dcesrv: NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER]
[2019/04/17 06:30:54.062619,  3] ../source4/smbd/service_stream.c:66(stream_terminate_connection)
  Terminating connection - 'dcesrv: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED'
[2019/04/17 06:30:54.062719,  3] ../source4/smbd/process_single.c:114(single_terminate)
  single_terminate: reason[dcesrv: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED]
[2019/04/17 06:30:54.065690,  3] ../lib/ldb-samba/ldb_wrap.c:325(ldb_wrap_connect)
  ldb_wrap open of secrets.ldb
[2019/04/17 06:30:54.069486,  3] ../source4/rpc_server/drsuapi/dcesrv_drsuapi.c:86(dcesrv_drsuapi_DsBind)
  ../source4/rpc_server/drsuapi/dcesrv_drsuapi.c:86: doing DsBind with system_session
[2019/04/17 06:30:54.071144,  3] ../lib/ldb-samba/ldb_wrap.c:325(ldb_wrap_connect)
  ldb_wrap open of secrets.ldb
[2019/04/17 06:30:54.074733,  3] ../source4/rpc_server/dcerpc_server.c:1644(dcesrv_request)
  Warning: 2 extra bytes in incoming RPC request
[2019/04/17 06:30:54.075361,  2] ../source4/rpc_server/drsuapi/getncchanges.c:1526(getncchanges_collect_objects)
  ../source4/rpc_server/drsuapi/getncchanges.c:1526: getncchanges on CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it using filter (uSNChanged>=1)
[2019/04/17 06:30:54.647685,  2] ../source4/rpc_server/drsuapi/getncchanges.c:2784(dcesrv_drsuapi_DsGetNCChanges)
  DsGetNCChanges with uSNChanged >= 1 flags 0x90200070 on <GUID=c2f90cf6-01eb-45c5-b379-a2f97011ae4b>;CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it gave 637 objects (done 1637/1637) 38 links (done 38/38 (as S-1-5-21-3824729860-2459181076-3710323013-500))
[2019/04/17 06:30:54.676728,  3] ../source4/smbd/service_stream.c:66(stream_terminate_connection)
  Terminating connection - 'dcesrv: NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER'
[2019/04/17 06:30:54.676908,  3] ../source4/smbd/process_single.c:114(single_terminate)
  single_terminate: reason[dcesrv: NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER]
[2019/04/17 06:30:54.681969,  3] ../source4/smbd/service_stream.c:66(stream_terminate_connection)
  Terminating connection - 'dcesrv: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED'
[2019/04/17 06:30:54.682063,  3] ../source4/smbd/process_single.c:114(single_terminate)
  single_terminate: reason[dcesrv: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED]
[2019/04/17 06:30:54.685299,  3] ../lib/ldb-samba/ldb_wrap.c:325(ldb_wrap_connect)
  ldb_wrap open of secrets.ldb
[2019/04/17 06:30:54.689293,  3] ../source4/rpc_server/drsuapi/dcesrv_drsuapi.c:86(dcesrv_drsuapi_DsBind)
  ../source4/rpc_server/drsuapi/dcesrv_drsuapi.c:86: doing DsBind with system_session
[2019/04/17 06:30:54.690899,  3] ../lib/ldb-samba/ldb_wrap.c:325(ldb_wrap_connect)
  ldb_wrap open of secrets.ldb
[2019/04/17 06:30:54.694367,  3] ../source4/rpc_server/dcerpc_server.c:1644(dcesrv_request)
  Warning: 2 extra bytes in incoming RPC request
[2019/04/17 06:30:54.695082,  2] ../source4/rpc_server/drsuapi/getncchanges.c:1526(getncchanges_collect_objects)
  ../source4/rpc_server/drsuapi/getncchanges.c:1526: getncchanges on CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it using filter (uSNChanged>=1)
```

in samba.log

The samba version is:

```
Samba version 4.6.7-Ubuntu
```

in the DCPROMO.LOG on windows server I can see this:

```
04/17/2019 07:24:02 [INFO] Promotion request for replica domain controller
04/17/2019 07:24:02 [INFO] DnsDomainName  mydomain.it
04/17/2019 07:24:02 [INFO]  ReplicaPartner  dc02.mydomain.it
04/17/2019 07:24:02 [INFO]  SiteName  Default-First-Site-Name
04/17/2019 07:24:02 [INFO]  DsDatabasePath  C:\Windows\NTDS, DsLogPath  C:\Windows\NTDS
04/17/2019 07:24:02 [INFO]  SystemVolumeRootPath  C:\Windows\SYSVOL
04/17/2019 07:24:02 [INFO]  Account (NULL)
04/17/2019 07:24:02 [INFO]  Options  1179840
04/17/2019 07:24:02 [INFO] Validate supplied paths
04/17/2019 07:24:02 [INFO] Validating path C:\Windows\NTDS.
04/17/2019 07:24:02 [INFO]  Path is a directory
04/17/2019 07:24:02 [INFO]  Path is on a fixed disk drive.
04/17/2019 07:24:02 [INFO] Validating path C:\Windows\NTDS.
04/17/2019 07:24:02 [INFO]  Path is a directory
04/17/2019 07:24:02 [INFO]  Path is on a fixed disk drive.
04/17/2019 07:24:02 [INFO] Validating path C:\Windows\SYSVOL.
04/17/2019 07:24:02 [INFO]  Path is on a fixed disk drive.
04/17/2019 07:24:02 [INFO]  Path is on an NTFS volume
04/17/2019 07:24:02 [INFO] Start the worker task
04/17/2019 07:24:02 [INFO] Request for promotion returning 0
04/17/2019 07:24:02 [INFO] Forcing time sync
04/17/2019 07:24:02 [INFO] Forcing a time sync with dc02.mydomain.it
04/17/2019 07:24:02 [INFO] Searching for a domain controller for the domain mydomain.it that contains the account DCWIN01$
04/17/2019 07:24:02 [INFO] Located domain controller dc02.mydomain.it for domain mydomain.it
04/17/2019 07:24:02 [INFO] Directing kerberos authentication to dc02.mydomain.it returns 0
04/17/2019 07:24:02 [INFO] DsRolepFlushKerberosTicketCache() successfully flushed the Kerberos ticket cache
04/17/2019 07:24:02 [INFO] Using site Default-First-Site-Name for server dc02.mydomain.it
04/17/2019 07:24:02 [INFO] Stopping service NETLOGON
04/17/2019 07:24:02 [INFO] Stopping service NETLOGON
04/17/2019 07:24:03 [INFO] Configuring service NETLOGON to 1 returned 0
04/17/2019 07:24:03 [INFO] Stopped NETLOGON
04/17/2019 07:24:03 [INFO] Deleting current sysvol path C:\Windows\SYSVOL 
04/17/2019 07:24:04 [INFO] Created system volume path
04/17/2019 07:24:04 [INFO] Copying initial Directory Service database file C:\Windows\system32\ntds.dit to C:\Windows\NTDS\ntds.dit
04/17/2019 07:24:04 [INFO] Installing the Directory Service
04/17/2019 07:24:04 [INFO] Calling NtdsInstall for mydomain.it
04/17/2019 07:24:04 [INFO] Starting Active Directory Domain Services installation
04/17/2019 07:24:04 [INFO] Validating user supplied options
04/17/2019 07:24:04 [INFO] Determining a site in which to install
04/17/2019 07:24:04 [INFO] Examining an existing forest...
04/17/2019 07:24:04 [INFO] Starting a replication cycle between dc02.mydomain.it and the RID operations master (dc01.mydomain.it), so that the new replica will be able to create users, groups, and computer objects...
04/17/2019 07:24:04 [INFO] Configuring the local computer to host Active Directory Domain Services
04/17/2019 07:24:04 [INFO] EVENTLOG (Warning): NTDS General / Service Control : 1539
Active Directory Domain Services could not disable the software-based disk write cache on the following hard disk.



Hard disk:
c:



Data might be lost during system failures.

04/17/2019 07:24:05 [INFO] EVENTLOG (Informational): NTDS General / Internal Processing : 2041
Duplicate event log entries were suppressed.



See the previous event log entry for details. An entry is considered a duplicate if
the event code and all of its insertion parameters are identical. The time period for
this run of duplicates is from the time of the previous event to the time of this event.



Event Code:
80000603

Number of duplicate entries: 
2

04/17/2019 07:24:05 [INFO] EVENTLOG (Warning): NTDS General / Internal Configuration : 1463
Active Directory Domain Services has detected and deleted some possibly corrupted indices as part of initialization.



These deleted indices will be rebuilt.

04/17/2019 07:24:07 [INFO] EVENTLOG (Informational): NTDS Database / Internal Processing : 2013
Active Directory Domain Services is rebuilding the following number of indices as part of the initialization process.



Indices: 
5

04/17/2019 07:24:07 [INFO] EVENTLOG (Informational): NTDS Database / Internal Processing : 2014
Active Directory Domain Services successfully completed rebuilding the following number of indices.



Indices: 
5

04/17/2019 07:24:07 [INFO] EVENTLOG (Informational): NTDS General / Internal Configuration : 2120
This Active Directory Domain Services server does not support the Recycle Bin. Deleted objects may be undeleted, however, when an object is undeleted, some attributes of that object may be lost.  Additionally, attributes of other objects that refer to the object being undeleted may also be lost.

04/17/2019 07:24:07 [INFO] Creating the NTDS Settings object for this Active Directory Domain Controller on the remote AD DC dc02.mydomain.it...
04/17/2019 07:24:07 [INFO] Replicating the schema directory partition
04/17/2019 07:24:08 [INFO] Replicating CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: received 1000 out of approximately 1552 objects
04/17/2019 07:24:09 [INFO] Replicating CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: received 1552 out of approximately 1552 objects
04/17/2019 07:24:09 [INFO] Replicated the schema container.
04/17/2019 07:24:09 [INFO] Active Directory Domain Services updated the schema cache.
04/17/2019 07:24:09 [INFO] Replicating the configuration directory partition
04/17/2019 07:24:10 [INFO] Replicating CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: received 1000 out of approximately 1638 objects
04/17/2019 07:24:10 [INFO] EVENTLOG (Informational): NTDS General / Replication : 1695
This directory service now supports linked-valued replication. Each value of a multivalued attribute now replicates individually to reduce network bandwidth and to provide a finer degree of conflict resolution.

04/17/2019 07:24:10 [INFO] Replicating CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: received 1611 out of approximately 1638 objects
04/17/2019 07:24:11 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:12 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:12 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:13 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:14 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:14 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:15 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:16 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:16 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:17 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:17 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:18 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:19 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:19 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:20 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:21 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:21 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:22 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:23 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:23 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:24 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:24 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:25 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:26 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:26 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:27 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:28 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:28 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:29 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:30 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:30 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:31 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:32 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
04/17/2019 07:24:32 [INFO] Replicating data CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=it: Received 1638 out of approximately 1638 objects and 19 out of approximately 19 distinguished name (DN) values...
```

Can you help me? Thank you

Comment: This might be better suited fot ServerFault

Comment: I needs to re-post to ServerFault or there is any option to move the post? Thanks